# VBA code to change Microsoft Word Document Classification

Tags: vba, ms-word, classification, document-classification

I am really sorry for the newbie question.

I have searched online for hours, and tried numerous options to see if I can do it, but haven’t got very far.

To start this question, I should say I am not a VBA coder by any stretch of the imagination, but I have created a document for my workplace that uses Rich text content controls (to provide guidelines in the document ensuring consistency), legacy form fields (to allow me to paste information into a set box based on selections) etc. 
This document requires protection (and a password) to stop anyone editing it and to allow the legacy form fields to work. 
I have proven that the document works with around 1000 completed documents so far. 
I appreciate it is probably not the neatest of solutions, but the company is happy with it. 
A by product of the protection is that the document classification cannot be changed by the end user. 
For reasons unknown to me, the company want to have the ‘blank’ document to be listed as ‘internal’, while a completed document needs to be ‘restricted’. Because the document is protected it gives an error stating that the original document has a different classification and to contact the owner (me). 
So far, by cobbling together some information I have found online, I have managed to get a pop up box (via user form) to show when saving the document. 
I just cannot utilise these selections to change the document classification. 
As far as I can tell, the classification system is the standard Microsoft option (not a third party software) 
My question is, can this be done by VBA, even if I have to have the code remove the password, and then re-input the password. (I have done this for some other macros on the document. So I know that much). 
If it is possible, can you point me in the direction of where to start.

Comment: Are you using [File Classification Infrastructure (FCI)](http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/windows-server-2012-file-classification-infrastructure)?

Comment: Hi @JoelSpolsky. I don’t think so. I believe we have a very simple selection using the Microsoft Data Classification Toolkit. There is no system selection that takes place, or any official storage solution based on classification. All we have is 4 options on the menu in MS Word (highly restricted, restricted, internal, and public). When a document is created/edited the user then selects the classification based on our own rules. There is no system restriction on distribution or storage based on classification. It’s solely used for the footers on the documents.

Comment: FWIW what you describe is not part of Microsoft Word and is not part of its object model. I don't know whether this functionality is exposed in any way VBA can access it...

Comment: You say you're using content controls and formfields in the same document. You really shouldn't do that, since they weren't designed to work together and doing so is known to cause problems. FWIW content controls work with/without editing restrictions and, if desired, can work with either 'read only' (with exceptions) and 'filling in forms' protection.